# How to add fragments to a pageViewer?

Tags: android

I'm following some example code [here](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/android-tabs-viewpager-swipe-able-tabs-ftw/). I'm trying to understand the steps involved to instantiate a fragment and then add it to the ViewPager.

I think I understand that fragments.add() adds the fragment to the ViewPager. I'm not sure I understand what Fragment.instantiate() does. [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#instantiate%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29) say that it needs a "context" for instantiating. What does that mean?

```
private void setupViewPager() {

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentTab1.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentTab2.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentTab3.class.getName()));

    this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    //
    this.mViewPager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Context is used to get the classloader i.e. the classloader used to retrieve the container activity from the package.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#instantiate(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)